# When is Calling Connection.setTransactionIsolation safe?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions

The Java reference documentation specifies that if a Connection.setTransactionIsolation() method is called during a transaction, then the results are implementation defined.

When does a transaction begin in JDBC? I assume it begins when you call "execute" on a statement.

So will calling setTransactionIsolation after calling Connection.prepareStatement() but before the PreparedStatement is executed, produce implementation independent, predictable results?